# Whats the way to add base url to the Reactjs Docker image

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a ReactJS app that talks to backend api to fetch and modify data. The React app is deployed as Docker image from Nginx:alpine inside the Kubernetes cluster, also, the nginx routes the api requests to the backend api. For example, in uat the api would be `https://uat.mycompanydomain.com/app1/api` would route to the backend service that is not exposed outside directly.

Appliction is built at two stages - one for the development, two for the uat & production release.

As of now, the app receives the backend `api_url` (prod-> `https://mycompanydomain.com/app1/api`) as environment variable during the Docker image build, and is burnt into the image itself. Because, this env variable couldn't not be overridden using the env passed as `Configmap` or `env` variables during deployment. Internally the app use `REACT_APP_API_URL` to read the value.

What is the best way to pass the `api_url` dynamically to the app so that the application works using this variable irrespective of where it is deployed.

PS: The app has `homepage` variable set in `package.json` with the subdirectory it is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) in your Dockerfile

```
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL=localhost
ENV REACT_APP_API_URL=$REACT_APP_API_URL
```

and then,

```
docker build \
  --build-arg REACT_APP_API_URL=$REACT_APP_API_URL .
```

Comment: Yes. But will that not add the `API_URL` into the docker image itself. So, should 
I then have to build one more image with different `API_URL` for production env?

Comment: Yes, you have to deal with two different images